# Why does SCAN/LAMBDA give unexpected results?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula

It is very possible that I dont understand the lambda logic or do I? I have dataset A2:A5 like:

```
1
3
6
10
```

If I do:  `=SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, aa+bb))` i get:

```
1
4
10
20
```

If I do: `=SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, ROW(bb)-1))` I get

```
1
2
3
4
```

if I run: `=SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, (aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)))` the result is

```
1
8
42
208
```

Why there is 42 and 208 ? How this results in such values? How can it be 42 and 208 ?

Expected result is

```
1
8
30
80
```

And I can get it with:

`=ArrayFormula(SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, aa+bb))*(ROW(A2:A5)-1))`

But not with

`=SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, (aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)))`

Comment: You need to understand how `REDUCE` operates to see how `SCAN` does.

Comment: For respondants, touch on this quoting the OP `And I can get it with: =ArrayFormula( ... But not with =SCAN` highlight the diffrance, please.

Comment: ..... [This answer's Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920148/scan-lambda-issue/73920765#73920765:~:text=but%20that%27s%20not%20how%20it%20works.%20to%20get%20your%20expected%20result%20and%20by%20not%20using%20your%20formula%20where%20ROW%20is%20outside%20of%20SCAN%3A) " `Arrayformula` but not `SCAN` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

above answers pretty much contain all so I will add only this:

you probably expected that by doing `(aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)` you will get:

| (aa+bb) | * | (ROW(bb)-1) |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | * | 1 | = | 1 |
| 4 | * | 2 | = | 8 |
| 10 | * | 3 | = | 30 |
| 20 | * | 4 | = | 80 |

but that's not how it works. to get your expected result and by not using your formula where ROW is outside of SCAN:

> `=ArrayFormula(SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, aa+bb))*(ROW(A2:A5)-1))`

you would need to do:

```
=INDEX(MAP(SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, (aa+bb))), ROW(A2:A5)-1, LAMBDA(cc, dd, cc*dd)))
```

where `cc` is the entire SCAN and `dd` is `ROW(A2:A5)-1` eg. first do the running total and then multiplication, which is not so feasible length-wise.

or shorter but with SEQUENCE:

```
=MAP(SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, (aa+bb))), SEQUENCE(4), LAMBDA(cc, dd, cc*dd))
```

Comment: `ROW is outside SCAN` this is the key.

Answer (score 2):

`SCAN` is a great intermediate results function. To understand how `SCAN` operates, you need to understand how `REDUCE` operates. The syntax is:

```
=REDUCE(initial_value, array, LAMBDA(accumulator, current_value, some_function()))
```

Going through `=SCAN(0, A2:A5, LAMBDA(aa, bb, (aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)))` step by step,

- A2:A5 is 1,3,6,10
- Step 1:

  - `aa` = 0(`initial_value`)
  - `bb` = 1(`current_value`:A2)
  - Result(`(aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)`): (0+1)*(2-1)=1
- Step 2:

  - `aa` = 1(`accumulator`(previous return value))
  - `bb` = 3(`current_value`:A3)
  - Result(`(aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)`): (1+3)*(3-1)=8
- Step 3:

  - `aa` = 8(`accumulator`(previous return value))
  - `bb` = 6(`current_value`:A4)
  - Result(`(aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)`): (8+6)*(4-1)=42
- Step 4:

  - `aa` = 42(`accumulator`(previous return value))
  - `bb` = 10(`current_value`:A5)
  - Result(`(aa+bb)*(ROW(bb)-1)`): (42+10)*(5-1)=52*4=208

Answer (score 2):

aa stores the result of the previous calculation, so you have:

[image]